# Saving interactive series on matplotlib figures (html)

Tags: python, matplotlib, mpld3

I have an example (from matplotlib) for an interactive plot where I can select from the series which lines I want to display on the plot. This works perfectly but now I want to export this to an html. I can successfully do this with `mpld3.save_html()` but lose the interactivity on the series selection.
Here's the code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt, mpld3
from matplotlib.widgets import CheckButtons

t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s0 = np.sin(2*np.pi*t)
s1 = np.sin(4*np.pi*t)
s2 = np.sin(6*np.pi*t)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
l0, = ax.plot(t, s0, visible=False, lw=2)
l1, = ax.plot(t, s1, lw=2)
l2, = ax.plot(t, s2, lw=2)
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.2)

rax = plt.axes([0.05, 0.4, 0.1, 0.15])
check = CheckButtons(rax, ('2 Hz', '4 Hz', '6 Hz'), (False, True, True))

def func(label):
    if label == '2 Hz': l0.set_visible(not l0.get_visible())
    elif label == '4 Hz': l1.set_visible(not l1.get_visible())
    elif label == '6 Hz': l2.set_visible(not l2.get_visible())
    plt.draw()
check.on_clicked(func)

mpld3.save_html(fig, 'interactive_fig.html') #save to html here
plt.show()
```

Is there a way to maintain this interactivity???

I have also tried saving with pickle but still lose the series interaction.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not possible to maintain the `matplotlib.widget` interactivity in an html file generated by `mpld3`.  This is because the javascript generated by `mpld3` runs client-side and cannot access the Python kernel that generated it.

You can achieve something like the `matplotlib` interactivity in an html version using the [Static Interactive Widgets for IPython Notebooks](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2013/12/05/static-interactive-widgets/) approach.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Are there any other modules in python that can generate these interactive plots?

Comment: Check out the `bokeh` project, too.

Comment: Thanks. I have had a look at `bokeh` but can't find anything for interactive series selection. Any suggestions?

Comment: also check out plotly (https://plot.ly/python/). The plots stay interactive when you save the notebook as an html file.

Comment: Static Interactive widgets now seem to be out of date with no obvious successor?