# How can I save a matplotlib figure with HTML to keep the dynamic functionnalities (zooming...)?

Tags: python, html, matplotlib

```
plt.savefig()
```

only allows to save png or jpg figures. I want to save an HTML figure, so that others can still zoom in.

Comment: did you try the answers in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49015957/how-to-get-python-graph-output-into-html-webpage-directly) question ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Saving interactive series on matplotlib figures (html)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33012025/saving-interactive-series-on-matplotlib-figures-html)